# Operating system information of User in Shiny app

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I need to customise based on the OS of user. Is there any way to get that information in my `Shiny app`? The `session$clientData` information doesnt appear to provide that.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some `js` to get it from a browser. `shiny:sessioninitialized` is to wait for server to fully load

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script("$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('os_version',  window.navigator.platform);});")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$os_version,{
        print(input$os_version)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]